# Code First - не создаеся БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

В конструкторе класса контекста есть метод

```
public class ForumContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
```

`Database.EnsureCreated()` - который по инструкции при создании контекста автоматически проверяет наличие базы данных и, если она отсуствует, создает ее.

*Вот он мне как раз и ругается*:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'
```

*Предварительно я внедрил* `DbCotext` в классе `Startup.cs`

```
 public class Startup
        {
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                  services.AddDbContext<ForumContext>(options =>      
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ForumConnection")));
            }

        *******
    }
```

Comment: Подключение к БД настроено правильно? Драйвера СУБД установлены?

Comment: @Streletz все настроено..

Comment: Попробуйка заменит ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base() => ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base(options)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, но оно какое-то не тривиальное.
Помимо вышеуказзанного внедрения `DbCotext` в классе `Startup.cs`, реализовал метод `OnConfiguring` у `ForumContext`

```
public class ForumContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("conection strig");
            }
        }
    }
```

Однако дальше столкнулся с парадоксом --> [продолжение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949935/code-first-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)