# Code First - не создаеся БД (продолжаем искать решение)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, fluent-interface

Есть некая модель пользователя

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public IList<Profile> Profiles { get; set; } = new List<Profile>();
    }

public class Profile
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Bithday { get; set; }
        public string ImgSource { get; set; } = "defoult Img sorcse address";

        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть контекст из [предыдущей статьи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949826/code-first-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%91%D0%94) с реализованным методом `OnModelCreatihg`

```
public class ForumContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }

        public ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("cs");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(u => u.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Id).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Profiles).WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey(u => u.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(
                new User[]
                {
                    new User {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Email = "email_1", Password = "****"},
                    new User {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Email = "email_2", Password = "****"}
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().ToTable("Profile").HasKey(p => p.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().Property(u => u.Id).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasData(
                new Profile[]
                {
                    new Profile {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Roman" },
                    new Profile {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Sergey" }
                });
        }
    }
```

Приложение запускается и работает - ни каких ошибок, но БД в итоге не создается. 
Прочитал что ORM где-то у себя создает очередь запросов и отправляет их в БД. 
У меня я так понял не происходит отправка.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Code First - не создаеся БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949826/code-first-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%91%d0%94)

Comment: @Verng - тут проблема в другом, но она как бы вытекает из первого решения

Comment: почитал предыдущий вопрос, текущий... скажите, а может вам просто использовать миграции вместо механизма EnsureCreated? Просто удалите эти строки, прям весь конструктор закомментируйте - и всё. До момента пока схема база не поменяется - проблем вообще не будет ни с созданием базы, ни с запросами.

Comment: Согласен с @AK, гораздо лучше миграциями это сделать